# How to parse and obtain correlating column values in c#/sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

In the code below I query my SQlite database and parse it to see if there are any values in the column maxlen which are > 30. I then add these values to a list which I later use to show the user.

**What I want:**

Now if there is a value in maxLen >30 I want to be able to know what Seq (column) value is correlated to that.

Example: (I know these are not > 30 but) Say I want the values 3, 4, and 10 from the MaxLen column. But with these I also want the correlating Seq values which are 1, 2, 3. How would that be done?

[image]

```
string sql4 = "select * from abc";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql4, sqlite_conn);

SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    // Parse Max Length Column
    int maxlen;
    if (int.TryParse(reader["MaxLen"].ToString(), out maxlen))
        if (maxlen> 30.00)
        {
            MaxLen.Add(maxlen);
            maxlen1 = true;
        }
}
```

Edit: is this how I would do it?

```
string sql4 = "select seq, maxLen from abc where maxLen > 30";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql4, sqlite_conn);

// The datareader allows us to read the table abc row by row
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


while (reader.Read())
{
    // Parse Seq column
    int seq;
int maxLen1;
    if (int.TryParse(reader["Seq"].ToString(), out seq) && int.TryParse(reader["maxLen"].ToString(), out maxLen1))
{
    SeqIrregularities.Add(seq);
    NewList.Add(maxLen1); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know SQLiteCommand but there should be a method similar to reader.GetInt32("Seq") so you don't need "TryParse" when retrieving data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the `Seq` values and the `MaxLen` values that are greater than 30 then using `select * from abc` might not be appropriate. If you do so you will have to process/filter them in your `C#` code.

Why don't you get them already filtered in your query and simplify all the calculations in `C#`?

You can use this:

```
select seq, maxLen from abc where maxLen > 30
```

And then iterate over this (already filtered) results.

Note you should add any other field that you want to the `select` clause.

Comment: is the above how I would do it ?

Comment: Well, I don't exactly know what you want to do but that seems fine to me. I mean, you don't need to check for `maxLen > 30` in your code as it is already filtered

Comment: your answer helps me with selecting values >30 initially  BUT it doesn't help me  CORRELATE those maxLen values to Seq values. For example, say I there are only 3 maxlen values >30, however it will still read all Seq values

Comment: If you select both fields and use the query provided in the answer **you will get both values from the same row (correlated)**. If you still think that the answer doesn't correlate the results then I invite you to create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and reproduce the behaviour you're mentioning. That way we can both see the not working or not working solution